# Can I use Order By and ToLower to perform a case-insensitive string sort on DocumentDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I would like to sort the records in my DocumentDB collection alphabetically by their title.  At first I thought this was working:

```
SELECT c.Title  FROM c ORDER BY c.Title
```

But as would be expected this sorts lowercase letters after uppercase.  I would like my search to be case insensitive, so I tried this:

```
SELECT c.Title  FROM c order by LOWER(c.Title)
```

and this:

```
SELECT LOWER(c.Title) AS title FROM c ORDER BY title
```

but both of these generate errors.  How can I perform a case-insensitive string sort?

Comment: Hi @devrobf, I just discovered your post because I'm having the same trouble and I noticed your question was 5years ago. Did you find any better solution for this? I don't like the idea of duplicate all the string fields that I'm planning to use in an OrderBy. This is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69572033/cosmosdb-case-sensitive-order-by-expression) from today.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I did - although I haven't used DocumentDB since this question so things may have moved on!  Good luck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do case insensitive search is to add a separate field that is created with lower case of corresponding field (in this case Title). DocumentDB provides an efficient auto-index mechanism which adds little to no overhead for adding another extra field.

Once you have the extra field, point your lower case queries to the new field.

Comment: I hate that this is the best solution DocumentDB has, but I think you're right!  The only other thing I thought of was using a UDF, but it'll be much easier to use a computed field than figuring out how that works and whether it can be used in an Order By.