# Case insensitive ORDER BY for cosmos query

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

This question is pretty much the same as [Can I use Order By and ToLower to perform a case-insensitive string sort on DocumentDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919101) but since it was asked over 5 years ago I thought I'd raise the issue again.

For my situation, I have the model created via EFCore, and the sort is dynamically applied. If there is no better solution that the answer suggested in the above, I am happy to have a lowercase field site next to the normal field, as long as the field can be set as part of the EF insert/update operation without having to add new fields and value converters the model object.

Does anyone know of a better way?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in mechanism for case-insensitive sorting - you'll need to store a version of your content content normalized (either all upper-case or all lower-case, for sorting purposes), just as that [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920487/272109) suggests.

However: for matching within a query, Cosmos DB now has case-insensitive string functions, such as `StringEquals()`. So you can now do something like:

```sql
SELECT c.id
FROM c
WHERE StringEquals(c.SomeProperty, "someValue", true)
```

The third parameter (boolean), set to `true`, provides a case-insensitive comparison.

You'll probably want to do some benchmarking to compare performance to case-sensitive queries, so that you can decide whether this works for you.

There are also `StartsWith()`, `EndsWith()`, and `Contains()` that support case-insensitive matching.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your answer. I thought it would be the case the the sorting would not be case insensitive without the normalised field. I'm happy to do that, but instead of manually setting the normalised field, I'm looking for something that will do that automatically via EF. There could be a number of fields that are "sortable" for a given table, and there will be more tables with sortable fields. I'm looking for something re-usable.

Comment: @zXynK Ah - yeah, sorry, I can't speak to EF, as that's not something I work with...