# Sorting order is not working - Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have below query to sort my records based on Name_en_us value, ran this query from Azure portal, Cosmos DB data explorer.

```
SELECT top 10 c.Name_en_us FROM c where c.OrganizationID = "101" order by c.Name_en_us asc
```

Got below results

```
[
{
    "Name_en_us": "Communication"
},
{
    "Name_en_us": "Communication - 1st message after X hours"
},
{
    "Name_en_us": "Communication - Close Thread"
},
{
    "Name_en_us": "Communication - No active Conversation"
},
{
    "Name_en_us": "Dot Net testing"
},
{
    "Name_en_us": "bug_testing" <=======
},
{
    "Name_en_us": "dev_22-06"
},
{
    "Name_en_us": "dev_bug"
},
{
    "Name_en_us": "devtest"
},
{
    "Name_en_us": "devtest_Copy"
}
```

]

One of the result item "bug_test" in not in sort order and appeared in between other items.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Sorting is working, but it seems that it is case sensitive (ie first all Uppercase values, then all lowercase values) ...

Comment: @derpirscher need to sort irrespective of lower case or upper case.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69268191/272109) - tl;dr you'll have to store case-normalized (all upper-case, or all lower-case) content for sort purposes, perhaps in a secondary property, while leaving your original property intact.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive ORDER BY for cosmos query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69268078/case-insensitive-order-by-for-cosmos-query)

Answer (score -3):

> Any suggestions?

As suggested by `@David Makogon` and `@derpirscher` in the above comments, the sort is working fine.

Thanks `@David Makogon` for the alternate approach to make case-normalized either Upper or Lower case for the sorting purpose.

So better to do case insensitive searching by adding a new field with respect to the lower / upper case based on your target field.

Here below is my sample code and result for the same scenario reproduced.

***Sample code with `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` Clause***

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.category FROM c
WHERE c.category ="ITI"
ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

***Result:***

[image]

***Sample code with case-insensitive string function - `StringEquals()`***

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.category FROM c
WHERE c.category ="ITI" 
AND StringEquals(c.name, "Abc", true)
ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

***Result:***

[image]

Comment: There was no need to turn this into an answer. It's literally answered on another question. This question needs to be closed as a duplicate (but it can't be, as the answer I pointed to is an unaccepted answer). Just vote to close as documentation, since it can't be marked as duplicate.  Please don't just take my comment and turn it into an answer - I could have easily done that myself if this wasn't already answered elsewhere. Also, in future answers (not this one - it should be deleted), please be sure to use formatted text, not images of text.

Comment: Also: Any string function for comparison will require a complete collection scan (e.g. it will be a very expensive operation).