# CosmosDB case sensitive ORDER BY expression

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following use case:

I have a collection in CosmosDB and I'm exposing an endpoint to paginate and sort the elements within the container. I accept `continuationToken`, `sortBy` and `sortDirection` query string parameters and I allow the search by a subset of the fields like: CreatedDate,UpdatedDate,Name, etc. Everything seemed to be working just fine until I realized that CosmosDB is case sensitive and when I try to sort by Name for example:

```sql
SELECT c.Name FROM c order by c.Name asc
```

I will get back results like this:

```
["ACool name", "Cool name", "Some other name", "acooler name"]
```

and the order is not the expected one.

I did some research and so far the best approach I found is create a normalized field with `.ToUpper()` or `.ToLower()`. My concern with this approach is we might end up by duplicating all the fields that can be sorted. There is any way to define the index for an specific field to be case insensitive or someone can suggest a better approach? I think this is a common use case.

Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer to a near-identical question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69268078/272109) - tl;dr there is no built-in case-insensitive sorting built-in, although there are case-insensitive string functions now.

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon, thanks for your reply. I'm not sure how using `StartsWith()`, `EndsWith()` or `Contains()` I can achieve the desirable sort but I found in your question a reference to another one which is pretty similar to mine. In that one, the accepted answer was to create an extra normalized column and it has no activity in the past 5 years

Comment: Right - that question (well, the answer) is still valid, and I'm voting for this one to be marked as a duplicate, since they are essentially the same. My only point with the case-insensitive string functions was that there are now queries that can be done without having to store separate all-lower or all-upper versions of strings. This does not help with sorting. You'd have to do that client-side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use Order By and ToLower to perform a case-insensitive string sort on DocumentDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919101/can-i-use-order-by-and-tolower-to-perform-a-case-insensitive-string-sort-on-docu)

Comment: @DavidMakogon not exactly, as I mention in the description, the original reason for this question was to avoid the creation of the new field for each sortable string field on the model. The answer on the other question was 5 years ago and I was hoping to have a better solution now.

Comment: Right - but... the answer is the same today as it was 5 years ago. Nothing has changed regarding sorting.